# How does multiple scheduling work in Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have several shceduling proccess in laravel kernel.php file

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\firstController@index')
             ->everyMinute()->name('firstController_cronjob')->withoutOverlapping();
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\secondController@index')
             ->everyMinute()->name('secondController_cronjob')->withoutOverlapping();
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\thirdController@index')
             ->everyMinute()->name('thirdController_cronjob')->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

My question is how it's going to be done this three cronjobs? The tasks going to be run one by one or server going to make three jobs in one request ?

Thanks

Comment: provide all related data. inside the `console` folder.

Comment: I dont add anything in commands folder. I just need to make requests to my controllers. I just add this code in kernel.php file.

Comment: Read this docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling this will help you to understand how it works.

Comment: I have read the docs, I just wonder how it's going to be done multiple cron jobs? For example when first job is done, how laravel going to understand that now it is turn for second job and execute the second one?

Comment: You can launch them as 3 different commands in common crontab, not laravel scheduler.

Comment: @Lusine Martirosyan have u got any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Please check out the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#background-tasks)!

> By default, multiple commands scheduled at the same time will execute sequentially based on the order they are defined in your schedule method.

Answer (score 0):

The schedule method will run line by line so first schedule will run every minute firstController@index after this is finished the second is triggered and the the third. The withoutOverlapping will take care that all of them will not overlap with some other cron jobs.

here is a link to the documentation. Please read trough it for a better grip over cron jobs in laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#defining-schedules

Comment: So is there a way to run my cronjobs for controllers parallel. I don't need them to be run one by one, I need paraller task scheduling. Is there a way for that?

Comment: Make a test with the code that you have but remove withoutOverlapping().

Comment: No, by removing withoutOVerlapping I won't get what I want. In that case I'm gonna to get the same task requested not finished it. I want to make parallel requests to my controllers

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know.

It is run sequentially.

Your sub-question seems to be:
"How can I make them run in parallel, without ditching the withoutOverlapping()?"

In that case, you can use: runInBackground()
withoutOverlapping() can be preserved using the above method.

Alternatively, you could also just call the commands, for the jobs you want to run simultaneously, in your crontab..
But I'd prefer to keep it centralized in Kernel.php